# How to ensure global temp table sticks around

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, t-sql

In the **foreach** statement, there will be around 5 different stored procedures that will be called that all rely on the same global temp table.

Because we might have 100 different threads of this method running at the same time, how do I ensure that:

**how do i ensure that the global temp table sticks around ONLY for the duration of this method **Updatetroup**?**

```
private DataTable Updatetroup(ProductCatalogSyncData syncDataModel, string connectionString)
{
    var ds = syncDataModel.SyncDataSet;
    var troupCommand = new SqlCommand();
    var troupConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    var dtResults = new DataTable("BillingIds");
    var syncConfig = syncDataModel.XDataMapping;

    string EntityName;
    //inside of this foreach statement is where i am calling multiple stored procedures that need to make use of the same global temporary table
    foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
    {
        EntityName =
            StringDefaultIfNull(
                syncConfig.Root.XPathSelectElement("./entity[@name='" + dt.TableName + "']"),
                "troupTableName").Substring(3);

        troupCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        troupCommand.CommandText = "troup720_P_" + EntityName + "Sync";

        var entityNameParam = new SqlParameter("@EntityName", dt.TableName);
        troupCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        troupCommand.Parameters.Add(entityNameParam);
        var tblParam = new SqlParameter("@O720_" + EntityName, SqlDbType.Structured);
        tblParam.Value = dt;
        troupCommand.Parameters.Add(tblParam);

        troupCommand.Connection = troupConnection;

        try
        {

            // Define the data adapter and fill the dataset 
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(troupCommand))
            {
                da.Fill(dtResults);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (troupConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                troupConnection.Close();
        }
    }
    return dtResults;
}
```

**Assuming this method is called by 100 different threads, how do I neatly make sure that each thread ONLY gets its own global temporary table?**

Comment: Global temp tables are just that...global. There is no conditional global scope. A global temp table will available to ANY connection while it exists and it will be removed once there are no connections referencing it. Sounds to me like a global temp is now what you need here at all. You are going to have massive concurrency issues. However, if you create a temp table it will be available to any procedures that are called from the procedure that created it. And it would be thread safe.

Comment: @SeanLange if i convert my global temp to a regular temp, will that regular temp be accessible to everything inside of the method above?

Comment: Not the way you have this coded at the moment. Right now you are closing and reopening your connection on each iteration through your loop. Ideally you should not do this regardless of your temp table. What you should be doing is wrapping your connection in a USING statement and keeping it open for the duration of your loop. Then if you create your temp table prior to looping it will be available the entire time because the temp table belongs to the connection.

Comment: Suggestion: rather than creating a temp table, create a table with some means of identifying your rows (e.g., put in a `newid` column & load that in with every row).  This will get you out of worrying about temp persistence, will let you actually examine the data mid-stream, and will let you manage the lifecycle of the data by purging it at whatever point you think it should be purged, rather than relying upon the db engine to do so.  The problem with global temp is that you cannot guarantee its persistence - you may run into a condition wherein the global temp gets purged & then you're stuck.

Comment: So you want a global temp table that is essentially not global at all and not bound by temporariness as the database sees fit. @DavidT.Macknet is right - just properly design and use a table for your needs. A table has all the facilities you want and need.